# How can I make a plane always look at camera?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, constraints, drivers

How can I make a plane always look at camera? Like in old videogames, like Doom or Wolfenstein, this kind of software used static images that always looked at the camera, is this possible to make on Blender Cycles?

Comment: did you try track to constraint ?

Comment: Do you mean the ''Track To'' constraint?

Comment: yes the constraint

Comment: I think it worked, but now i tried with the'' Copy Rotation ''and it worked! thanks :)

Comment: please write your solution as answer here

Comment: You could make the camera as parent and the plane as child

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13949/bge-problem-with-speech-bubbles/13963#13963

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think I know what you're talking about (cause I'm a huge fan of these kind of oldschool 3d-imitating games :)). You may use a ***Damped Track*** constraint.
[image]

Select the plane, go to *Constraints* header, select a ***Damped Track*** *constraint* and set the *Camera* as a ***Target***. Then select an axis you want a plane to lie on.
[image]

If you move the plane in any direction it'll always face the camera. Remember that you may also decrease the ***Influence*** of this *constraint* for different results.
[image]

Comment: that's what the question is about

Comment: Thank you! that's even a more better option that the one that i found :)

Comment: This works but what is even better when dealing with planes that need to follow the camera is to use "copy rotation" and then select the camera. The reason why is because the object is facing the camera as an object but not necessarily the lens. This is an issue if you deal with instances with many objects as when you zoom in the instances follow the original object which might not look into the lens of the camera. This is completely avoided with copying the rotation and object always face the lens directly.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but there is an add-on called **[Create camera image plane](http://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=287436&d=1391722170)** that creates a plane that always fills the frame, is always parallel to the camera and moves with it.

[image]

Here's a link to the original thread on where you can download it in [blenderartists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?300436-Scripts-Create-camera-image-plane&highlight=camera%20plane). (login is required to download attachments)

Comment: the last thread says : the add-on called Create camera image plane does not work in blender 2.76 because while plane is created, all vertices are stuck in the pivot point    
 
I'm talking about the add-on called Create camera image plane... – Marietto just now   edit

Comment: @Marietto I use it all the time. It works fine (I'm on blender 2.77)

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution to this, first select the Plane you want to track with the camera, and then the Object Constraints option, select 'Copy Rotation'

After that, select the Camera in the list next to the orange cube icon, and then just move the camera as usual, the camera will work as normally do but with a plane following automatically.

[image]

*Also, first be sure to put the plane in front of the camera as you want to show it.*

Comment: That won't point to it if you move it . . .

Comment: Oh, now that i tried, you're right, for the purpose that i needed (camera movement only) worked perfectly, but yes, if you move the object (plane) it will fail :/

Comment: the last thread says : it doesn't work in 2,76, while plane is created, all vertices are stuck in the pivot point

Comment: I'm talking about the add-on called Create camera image plane...