# How to bring always the front of view of a 2D animated character?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, camera

What can I do to animate a character showing only its front of view ? The problem is that it is done in two dimensions and when the camera shows it obliquely, is not good. how can I configure the x and y axys ? Even the duke nukem 3D character always shows only the front of view. thanks.

[image: this is a 2d character that I want to show only on the front of view]

Comment: Do you mean the effect like this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31564/how-can-i-make-a-plane-always-look-at-camera ?

Comment: yes,I wanted to do something like that,but the latest thread on the blendercommunity says : " it doesn't work in 2,76, while plane is created, all vertices are stuck in the pivot point "..and I'm using blender 2.76

Comment: Could you post a link to this BA thread, cause I am using 2.76 and it still works fine for me. Just put your camera perfectly in front of your plane/model (as in my duplicated answer), then add a constraint and it should work well.