# Video texture not rendering correct on different pc

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm simuating fire by using a video texture. (see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80954/6102 )
This works fine on my pc.

Now if I try to render on a different pc (I have tested 3 different pc's)  I get each time a sqhare instead of a nice explosion (where you only see the explosion from the video instead of the full rectangle of the texture being rendered).

[image]

The result should be a nice explosion (which I have on my other pc: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3gw9.gif )

Any idea what is wrong? I'm using the latest blender version (2.78c)

I have this setting:
[image]

and GPU compute with feature set supported is active.

My blender files also have "External data" -> "Automatically pack into .blend file" enabled, so the video texture should be enabled.

**Update:** this is a test file which works fine on my pc (shows the explosion nicely) but on the other pc's it shows just some kind of white rectangle.

[image]

Comment: Does the PC's run the exact same OS version? Is it possible that some third-party codecs have been installed on the "working" PC that haven't been installed the other ones?

Comment: 2pc's yes, one not. How do i know that?

Comment: Is it the "working" PC that has a different version? Try one of these methods: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/checking-installed-audio-and-video-codecs-on-your-computer/

Comment: I see some differences in codes but have no clue where they come from. :)

Comment: could there be anything other than a wrong codec? because the video file itself plays on every pc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't aware of this before but as mentioned below, Blender doesn't pack video files.

One solution would be to manually copy the avi file alongside the .blend-file.

Another would be to use the .png files that was supplied with the avi as an image sequence.

Comment: does this mean this is a bug in the packing because "External data" -> "Automatically pack into .blend file" is selected...

Comment: Video files cannot be packed into the .blend file.

Comment: is that something that could change in the future?

Comment: I personally doubt that it will change since video files in general are very large and it is probably better to separate them from the .blend-file.

Comment: There is a bug report (https://developer.blender.org/T33596) on this matter that were closed by Ton, with the comment:
"Yes, we don't support packing movies or sequences - for quite obvious reasons."